# Performance warning using TakeList and All on big lists

Tags: performance-tuning

According to *Mathematica*'s own documentation, [`TakeList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeList.html) can operate with lists containing `All`.  For example:

```
TakeList[Alphabet[], {2, 3, All}]
(* {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d", "e"}, {"f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", 
  "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", 
  "y", "z"}} *)
```

Recently I wanted to use that exact same functionality on a huge list (containing 5586977 elements), where those elements would be organized into 206694 ragged sublists.

When I used the `All` functionality alluded to above, my kernel "spun it's tires" for over 30 minutes until I finally killed the kernel.

Taking extra effort to replace `All` with an explicit integer allowed the same code to execute in 0.078 seconds.

I have confirmed this performance issue with *Wolfram [Case: 4223028]* and here is their reply:

> "Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support.
>
> As I understand, you were reporting issues with TakeList and All. I
>   was able to reproduce the slow evaluations you describe, and have
>   investigated the issue.
>
> It seems that TakeList is highly optimized for numeric lists as its
>   second argument. With All, more heuristics are required to handle the
>   flexibility and edge cases TakeList supports, and as such computation
>   time increases. In cases like the one you bring up, the increase in
>   computation time is significant.
>
> So while it is expected that using All would be slower, it would be
>   nice if the slowdown wasn't quite as dramatic. I have filed a
>   suggestion with our developers asking that we look to optimize things
>   here.
>
> We appreciate you taking the time to bring this to our attention.
>   Please do not hesitate to contact us with anything else you come
>   across while using our products."
>
> ---

I just wanted to make the user community aware of this extreme slowdown.

I have to admit a bit of frustration that *Wolfram* does not pay more attention to performance issues like this which really do happen frequently in the real world.